# How can I call a differect function after each onlick event

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to call a different function after each click. After the second click I want to disable to button. I believe I would use a conditional, but I don't know how to keep track of the clicks on a specific element.

Thanks

Here is the fiddle demo as well: http://jsfiddle.net/2w4YJ/

```
(function(){
    console.log("start of function");
    var studen1 = {name:"Walker", address:{street: "123 South Drive", city: 'Sarasota', state: 'FL'}, gpa: ["3.0 ", " 3.4", " 3.8"]};
    var studen2 = {name:"Christian", address:{street: "5601 Pebble Beach Ln", city: 'Sacromento', state: 'CA'}, gpa: [2.5, 3.6, 3.8]};
    var studen3 = {name:"Marisa", address:{street: "833 Golden Pond Ct", city: 'Osprey', state: 'FL'}, gpa: [4.0, 2.5, 3.0]};
    var button = document.querySelector('a');

    function loadStudent(){
        console.log("in load student");
        var eleName =    document.getElementById('name');
        var eleAddress =    document.getElementById('address');
        var eleGPA =    document.getElementById('gpa');

        eleName.innerHTML = studen1.name;
        eleAddress.innerHTML = studen1.address.street + "<br />" + studen1.address.city + "<br />" + studen1.address.state;
        eleGPA.innerHTML = studen1.gpa;
    };

    button.onclick = function(e){
        var clicks = 0;
        if(button.onclick = 1){
            console.log("1");
            loadStudent();
            clicks ++;
        } else if(clicks >= 1){
            console.log("2");
            clicks ++;
        } else{
            console.log("3");
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please take the time to clean up your code before posting it. There's far too much whitespace there.

Comment: `button.onclick = 1` this is an assignment, not a comparison. I recommend passing you r code through jshint to catch this sort of mistake.

Comment: where do you want clicks stored? inside a closure of button? where do you want loadStudent kept? in the botton.onclick function as well?

Answer (score 0):

move `var clicks` out of function scope. in you case every time function is fired click returns to zero value.

```
(function(){
        console.log("start of function");
        var clicks = 0;
        ...
```

and yes, in if statement use `==` or `===` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently redefining and resetting the click counter to zewro everytime the onclick handler is called. Try putting the declaration for `clicks` outside the event handler:

```
var clicks = 0; 
button.onclick = function(){
   clicks++;
   console.log(clicks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly

Comment: You can click the checkmark next to an aswer to mark it as accepted. Additionally, I would like to point out that you need to be careful as to how `clicks` is scoped. If you are initializing many buttons inside a for loop then you might end up having all of them share the same clicks counter (you can use the `(tunction(){}())` trick to avoid that, as some of the other answers pointed out.